# Vue 3 / Vite Bug? Using v-bind colon shorthand on <div id="xxx"> not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, okta-signin-widget

I ran across an oddity that I cannot yet ID and wanted to see if anyone knew if this was a bug in Vue 3 / Vite, or in Okta or just user error.

I'm implementing an okta authorization widget in Vue 3 (transitioning from Vue 2 actually), and found that if I used this statement with the colon included, it did not recognize the id of the  as being a valid name (the VueDevtools extension shows the  id= NaN), and the Okta widget never gets rendered:

`<div :id="okta-signin-container"></div>`

If I drop the colon like this:

`<div id="okta-signin-container"></div>`

then the okta widget gets rendered properly.

OR - as I'm reading further, is "id" just a native HTML marker that doesn't need a v-bind assignment? (I'm thinking this is my issue).

Comment: `:id="..."` syntax is only required if you're rendering something dynamic. In your case the second should be fine. If you want to use `:id`, then make that thing string (`:id="'okta-signin-container'"`), currently it tries to calculate the value of `okta - signin - container` (subtraction).

Comment: @brc-dd - are you saying that I should be using single quotes to ID the string, not double quotes? Your assertion to use single quotes inside double quotes looks odd/unnecessary? Also, if the :id="" *should* have worked, why did it not work? (Thx for the reply)

Comment: In Vue templates, if you write `:id="something"` that `something` is evaluated as JS, not as a simple string. So if you write `:id="'something'"` then it means that it's evaluated value will be that string. Otherwise it will try to find that variable `something` and will throw errors. In this case writing like this is completely unnecessary as for static things you should simple do `id="something"`. Read the docs - https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html

Comment: @brc-dd - thanks for your patient explanation. I read that document prior to my asking this question, but without your explicit explanation of "something" vs "'something'" I did not understand. I thought that leaving off the colon on :id vs id was just further shorthand and that the two statements were the exact same. Now I understand.